# How to generate two different structure xml from one class using JAXB

Tags: jaxb

I have two class, Node and Group, the Group is Node's sub-class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Node", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "children"
})
public class Node {

    protected int id;
    protected List<Node> children;
}
```

then Group class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Group", propOrder = {
    "name"
})
public class Group extends Node{
   protected String name;
}
```

I had define a class Tree to contain the Node class so after the marshal, xml will be

```
<tree>
  <children>
    <id>1</id>
    <children>
        <id>2</id>
    </children>
    <children>
        <id>3</id>
    </children>
  </children>
</tree>
```

There is another class Groups to contain all group in array, so I want the xml should be

```
<groups>
  <groups>
    <name>group-1</name>
  </groups>
  <groups>
    <name>group-2</name>
  </groups>
  <groups>
    <name>group-3</name>
  </groups>
</groups>
```

But because the Group inherited Node, so the second one always generate xml like this

```
<groups>
  <groups>
    <id>group-1</id>
    <name>group-1</name>
    <children>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>group-2</name>
    </children>
    <children>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>group-3</name>
    </children>
  <groups>
<groups>
```

How should I treat the two different class to different xml file even if they are inherited  related.
I need the object to handle things with current inherited design. So the inherited can't be removed.

If I add a @XmlTransient to Node's children property, the second xml will be the one I want, but the first xml can't generate as the one I want.

I'm confusing now and don't know how to do it.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple XML representations for an object model by leveraging an extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  This extension allows you to provide additional mappings via an XML representation.  For more information see:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML